# Javascript Promise: is the method name for resolve and reject arbitrary?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am confused on the concepts of `Promise`, `Resolve`, `Reject`, `then`, `catch`.

While I know how to write code that works, I want to clarify some questions:

Question 1:
Regarding `Resolve`, `Reject`, `then`, `catch`, Are these methods all introduced together with `Promise`? Before `Promise` is introduced to Javascript, does Javascript already have these special methods?

Question 2:
Are the method names `resolve, reject` that are passed as parameters to executor functions in Promise arbitrary?
For example:

```
const executorFunction = (resolve, reject) => {
  if ('1' === '1') {
      resolve('I resolved!');
  } else {
      reject('I rejected!'); 
  }
}
const myFirstPromise = new Promise(executorFunction);
```

This above code works well, no syntax error or anything. The promise will be in fulfilled state with `'I resolved!'` value.  But if I do:

```
const executorFunction = (A, B) => {
  if ('1' === '1') {
      A('I resolved!');
  } else {
      B('I rejected!'); 
  }
}
const myFirstPromise = new Promise(executorFunction);
```

Would it still work? Will the promise still be in fulfilled state with `'I resolved!'` value?

And to make it further, if I swap the method names:

```
const executorFunction = (reject, resolve) => {
  if ('1' === '1') {
      reject('I resolved!');
  } else {
      resolve('I rejected!'); 
  }
}
const myFirstPromise = new Promise(executorFunction);
```

Now, would this work? Will the promise still be in fulfilled state with `'I resolved!'` value?

Comment: `Will the promise still be in fulfilled state with 'I resolved!' value?` it's easy to test this for yourself - not like you can break anything :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is an object spec that was [included](https://medium.com/dailyjs/asynchronous-adventures-in-javascript-promises-1e0da27a3b4) with Javascript. Before Promise was included as part of Javascript, the same spec could be built via code.
2. Executor function is a function. Hence, it doesn't matter what the parameters are called, just their order.